# Android cocos2d adding child node throws nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, cocos2d-android

I am very much new to cocos2d.. I am developing an application in android using cocos2d.. In that,

```
public class BaseLayer extends CCLayer {

ChildLayer cl = new ChildLayer();
this.addChild(cl); ------------------------------>
}

public class ChildLayer extends CCLayer {

public ChildLayer() {
CCLayer.node();
}
.
.
}
```

In this, arrowed line throws the Null pointer exception..
Error Log is below..

```
E/AndroidRuntime(982): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 8
11-26 12:50:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(982): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 12:50:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(982): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCSprite.draw(CCSprite.java:871)
11-26 12:50:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(982): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCNode.visit(CCNode.java:674)
11-26 12:50:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(982): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCNode.visit(CCNode.java:680)
11-26 12:50:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(982): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCNode.visit(CCNode.java:680)
11-26 12:50:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(982): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCNode.visit(CCNode.java:680)
11-26 12:50:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(982): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.drawCCScene(CCDirector.java:683)
11-26 12:50:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(982): at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.onDrawFrame(CCDirector.java:651)
11-26 12:50:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(982): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1332)
11-26 12:50:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(982): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)
11-26 12:50:34.023: E/libEGL(982): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

I dont know how to resolve this issue.. I dont know why this occurs.. Since I am not much familiar with Cocos2d.. Please help me to resolve this issue. Somebody please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved.. In constructor,I have called the super class constructor like CCLayer.node()  instead of super()
I changed that and the problem is solved..